# ¿Cómo establezco y modifico valores de inputs?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos inputs donde el user intrduce valores, al hacer clic en un boton se obtendra la suma de dichos valores en otro input

Comment: Si puedes intenta poner un poco del código que has empleado para poder ayudarte más

Comment: Pasate por el foro de como elaborar una buena pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres entender, pero creo que quieres ver como obtengo los valores de los input.

Si este es el caso, puedes obtener el valor del input de la siguiente forma:

```js
/** Creamos una constante llamada myInput con el elemento Input **/
const myInput = document.getElementById('myIput')


/** Imprimimos en consola el valor 
*   escrito o el que esta por defecto
**/
console.log(myInput.value)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myIput" value="20" />
```

> Con la propiedad `value` accedemos al valor del input.

---

### Ejemplo

Ahora con esto aprendido, haremos una pequeña calculadora que sume dos numero y muestre el resultado en un input que por defecto solo este en modo de lectura.

```js
/** Creamos una constante contenedora del elemento boton **/
const button = document.getElementById("buttonSum")

/** 
*   Luego le decimos al boton que cuando el usuario
*   lo presione, ejecute la funcion `sumarNumeros`
**/

button.addEventListener('click', sumarNumeros)

/** Funcion que calculará el resultado y lo imprime */
function sumarNumeros() {
  /**Inputs donde el usuario escribe los numeros a sumar */
  const numeroUno = document.getElementById("inputUno")
  const numeroDos = document.getElementById("inputDos")
  
  /**Input donde imprimiremos el resultado */
  const resultado = document.getElementById("result")
  
  /** Validamos si los input tienen valores **/
  if(numeroUno.value.length && numeroDos.value.length) {
    /** Creamos una constante con el valor del resultado de la suma **/
    const sumaTotal = Number(numeroUno.value) + Number(numeroDos.value)  

    /** Asignamos el resultado al input resultado **/
    resultado.value = sumaTotal
  } else {
    alert("Rellene todos los campos")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inputUno" placeholder="Ingresa el primer numero" />
<input id="inputDos" placeholder="Ingresa el segundo numero" />

<button id="buttonSum">Sumar</button>

<br />
<br />

<input id="result" disabled placeholder="Acá verás tu resultado" />
```

> Espero que te ayude, todo el código está comentado.

Comment: no debes responder preguntas que no esten bien elaboradas mira [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JackNavaRow yo también hacia preguntas de ese tipo sin ninguna contexto, créeme que necesitaba a alguien que me ayudará, me pongo en sus zapatos, esta plataforma para ayudar.

Comment: Puedes ayudar!, pero el usuario no hizo ni siquiera un [Ejemplo Minimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) como se podria ayudar a alguien que por ahora no ha mostrado un intento de lo que hizo , y esto lleva a que los mismos usuarios vuelvan a hacer preguntas tipo examenes para que lo resolvamos

Comment: Es una respuesta barbara.. y esperemos que OP mejore la pregunta asi la podemos reabrir. El tema con estas preguntas, es que muchas veces OP ni siquiera vuelve, ni hablemos de aceptar tu respuesta o votarla positiva :(

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió la información